# I want to only use part of the filename in get-content

Tags: powershell

I have a folder of log files on a shared network drive.  I wrote a basic Powershell script to tail individual files.  They are named like this: 20220818-123.log
The script I made works by typing in the complete name of the file I want to view.  I added this line to set a date variable in the format of the file name:

```
$date= get-date -format yyyyMMdd-
```

But I can't figure out how to add it to the $filename variable, so that all I have to do is type in the 123 part of the name.

```
$filename= read-host -prompt "Enter filename"
get-content $filename -wait
```

Is it even possible to do what I want?  Like

```
$filename= $date (read-host -prompt "enter number").log
```

Which I know doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You could construct the filename in a number of ways, but I like the [-f (Format operator)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f) because it separates variable content from statci content:

```
$filename= read-host -prompt "Enter filename"
Get-Content ('{0:yyyymmdd}-{1}.log' -f (Get-Date) , $filename) -wait
```

Note that, as written, you only want to enter the `123` portion of the name, omitting `.log`, as that is taken care of by the filename construction as well.

Comment: I like this one, but I'm still just barely starting to learn Powershell.  I'm going to remember the -f operator for later use though for sure.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In another way or for better understanding.. you can construct your filename like this

```
$Today = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$spChar = "-"
$userInput = Read-host -Prompt "Enter Number"


$fileName = $Today+$spChar+$userInput

Get-Content "C:\temp\$filename.log"
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for what I wanted.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$Date     = Get-Date -format 'yyyyMMdd'
$FileName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the log filename after the '-'"
$FullName = $Date + '-' + $FileName + '.log'

Get-Content $FullName
```

Comment: I ended up using a combination of this and Dilly's answer.  Thank you